# How to make the radio button dynamic in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

here's the code:

***list.component.html***

```
<div class="sample" style="
          margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 100%;
        ">
          <nz-form-item *ngFor="let remark of tasks">
            <div nz-row nzType="flex" nzAlign="middle">
              <div nz-col nzSpan="14">
                {{ remark.description }}
              </div>
              <div nz-col nzSpan="10">
                <nz-form-control>
                  <nz-radio-group formControlName="radiostatus" [(ngModel)]="radioValue"
                    (ngModelChange)="onChangeStatus($event)">
                    <label nz-radio nzValue="passed">Passed</label>
                    <label nz-radio nzValue="failed">Failed</label>
                  </nz-radio-group>
                </nz-form-control>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div nz-row *ngIf="radioValue === 'failed'">
              <div nz-col nzSpan="24">
                <nz-form-control>
                  <textarea nz-input placeholder="Remarks" class="remarks-textarea" type="text" name="otherRemark"
                    formControlName="otherRemark" [(ngModel)]="otherRemark"
                    [nzAutosize]="{ minRows: 1, maxRows: 2 }"></textarea>
                </nz-form-control>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nz-form-item>
        </div>
```

***list.component.ts***

```
tasks = [
{
      "id": "ESOSA6aCrOER",
      "createdBy": "admin",
      "timeCreated": "2019-09-05 11:24:07",
      "updatedBy": "admin",
      "timeUpdated": "2019-09-05 11:24:07",
      "name": "Sample1",
      "description": "Desc1",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "type": "PM"
    },
    {
      "id": "1og6aSsrlG3nT",
      "createdBy": "admin",
      "timeCreated": "2019-09-05 11:31:18",
      "updatedBy": "admin",
      "timeUpdated": "2019-09-05 11:31:18",
      "name": "Sample2",
      "description": "DESC2",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "type": "PM"
    },
    {
      "id": "tbwndVAkYtql",
      "createdBy": "admin",
      "timeCreated": "2019-09-05 11:33:11",
      "updatedBy": "admin",
      "timeUpdated": "2019-09-05 11:33:11",
      "name": "SAMPLE4",
      "description": "DESC4",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "type": "PM"
    },
    {
      "id": "1cyNFwhR4cI9n",
      "createdBy": "admin",
      "timeCreated": "2019-09-05 11:56:12",
      "updatedBy": "admin",
      "timeUpdated": "2019-09-05 11:56:12",
      "name": "SAMPLE5",
      "description": "DESC5",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "type": "PM"
    },
    {
      "id": "1qJWWRwz2Q2fD",
      "createdBy": "admin",
      "timeCreated": "2019-11-28 15:51:02",
      "updatedBy": "admin",
      "timeUpdated": "2019-11-28 15:51:02",
      "name": "Task 0001",
      "description": "Task 0001 Description",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "type": "PM"
    },
]
```

What I want is when selecting radio button. it should not affect the other radio button. 
the problem is when I select the first item/radio button.
also the textarea, when I click the failed all textarea from the item will display, it shouldn't display affect the other.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to group the radio buttons in different groups for each remark of task.
I can see you have created radio buttons with group name radiostatus but for all your remarks group name remains same which shouldn't be the case. 
What you can do is add index to the for loop and then dynamically give different
names to different group according to remarks.

```
 <nz-form-item *ngFor="let remark of tasks; let i = index">
```

now while giving name to group name instead of giving hard coded value produce different name by using index.

```
[formControlName]="'radiostatus'+ i"
```